# Low Latency Streaming from /dev/video0 to HTML video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

A very simple illustration of what I would like to accomplish:

```
...
<video src='/dev/video0'...></video>
...
```

Now I realize the above isn't possible (at least how I wrote it) but I am looking for a way to **easily**(in as much as is possible) accomplish what it illustrates while maintaining low latency.

Things I've tried:

Gstreamer - kept getting a data stream error and the number of plug-ins was quite daunting
Jsmpeg - very poor latency
nodeStream - a github repo that gives a demo for streaming images via socket.io; had even worse latency
WebRTC (getUserMedia) - had great latency but only "gets" user media from the client side and /dev/video0 is serverside

I can post my code configurations for each but that would make this post very lengthy and if someone has an easy solution I haven't tried then there would be no need.

All thoughts welcome and appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: The "server" can be the "peer" in WebRTC.  If you're already using Gstreamer, you can use its built-in WebRTC stack!

Comment: Could you post a minimal example on how that might work?